# Remove subdomain from URLs with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I use subdomain routing with a laravel 4.2 application. Here's my routes file:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{keyword}.example.com'), function() {
    Route::get('/', 'FrontendHomeController@index');
});

Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'FrontendHomeController@index', 'as' => 'home']);
Route::get('hotels', ['uses' => 'FrontendHotelController@index', 'as' => 'hotelsearch']);
Route::get('hotel/{slug}/{id}', ['uses' => 'FrontendHotelController@detail', 'as' => 'hoteldetail']);
[...]
```

So I have a few pages which use subdomains like `keyword.example.com`, `another.example.com`. But most other pages are regular `example.com/page` URLs. This works fine so far. I generate the links for the navigation with Laravel url/route helpers, e.g. `{{ url('hotels') }}` or `{{ route('hotelsearch') }}`.

Now, on subdomain pages, the generated URL's have the subdomain included. E.g. on keyword.example.com, `{{ url('hotels') }}` generates `keyword.example.com/hotels` and not `example.com/hotels`.

**I would like to remove the subdomains for all links generated with the `url()` or `route()` helpers, these helpers should always point to the root domain.**

Is there a parameter or do I have to overwrite the helper methods somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` function in templates wraps `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::to`, which doesn't let you specify a domain, but you can use the same [`Route::group` technique](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#sub-domain-routing) to encapsulate all your primary domain routes. (It does not require a wildcard, as shown in the documentation.)

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'www.example.com'), function() {
    Route::get('hotels', ['uses' => 'FrontendHotelController@index', 'as' => 'hotelsearch']);
    // ...
});
```

Comment: That renders the subdomain URLs invalid, which is good. But it doesn't solve the problem with the `url`. However, it works with named routes (and the `route` helper)!

Comment: This actually works perfectly and generates base domain urls.